# dynatree: how to pass uniqueId for WebForm_DoCallback(first param,...) to onActivate: function (node)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, callback, dynatree

I want to call WebForm_DoCallback method when node is clicked

```
$("#tree").dynatree({
    onActivate: function (node) {
        ..something..
        WebForm_DoCallback(uniqueId, callBackArgument, ReceiveCallBackData, "", null, true);
 });
```

The idea is to pass the node.key to a asp.net page.
I am new in jquery and all that callback stuff, so please tell me if the whole approach is wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

I created javasrcript class and property that receive uniqueId of the page.
Then i pass that property to WebForm_DoCallback method.